# Text to PDF without losing/destroying the set tabs

Tags: pdf, text, textedit, tabs

I tried to print out a huge text file to a PDF file (DIN A4 landscape or A3 landscape). Unfortunately, every way I try, I always lose the formatting of the tabs I used for tabbing some tables with the tabulator key.

The problem seems to be, that PDF does not see the tabs or rather "translates" them to spaces of different width or whatever. Basically all (primitively done) tables are gone after converting to PDF, but in GEdit and TextEdit with a Monotype style font everything looks nice.

I just do not have a clue how to avoid this. Actually, I just want to have a one-to-one translation from a text file to a PDF, without having to work over 60 pages of tabbed tables.

Comment: Are your files simply .txt? In TextEdit you can change extension to .rtf and for this mode the export to .pdf keeps the tabs as the original. Also you can insert tables.

Comment: `open -a Safari foo.txt` and save to PDF using Print.

Comment: Thanks, Yoan, but changing to RTF just destroys/removes all tabulators, as well.

Comment: Thanks, Ihf, but that way is the same like TextEdit's way to print to PDF or even worse, because there I cannot choose the size (DIN A4 or A3) or format (landscape). Also, the tabulators get lost, too.

Comment: Check out smallpdf.com It's one of my favorite online apps for messing with tricky pdf issues. They seem to be able to fix most of the issues I get into. Their PDF converter might create the pdf you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, GoofyMonkey, but I am not willing to pay for something, I am not even sure about it will work. Also, I find this issue so basically weird, there must be a simpler and cost-free solution.

Comment: what xact font are you using and does the PDF understand it?

Comment: I think, on a Mac it is the standard TextEdit fixed-width font "Menlo". Yes, I just checked it.